# Properly contained

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to find a P(X) (powerset) where X has, say, 8 elements.

Then I know that P(X) has $2^8$ elements, but how many of these are properly contained (proper subset) in X? How do I find this out?

I'd think it was just 8 plus the empty set??

Comment: Don't think. Stick to the definitions. When you have understood them well, you can think again. Until you do, whenever you see a term like "properly contained", go to the definition. Unwind all the definitions, until the very last one of them. It's a long process, but you cannot make mistakes like that, and at the end you learn a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All $2^8$ except for $X$ itself: $2^8 -1$ of the subsets are proper subsets of the set $X$.

In other words, the only non-proper subset of a set is the set itself.